# Passing Query String to a User defined function in Mysql and returning the records' count

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test(query longtext) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE records INT;
  //maybe use prepared statements
  /* DECLARE querynew LONGTEXT;
  SET querynew := replace(query, 'SELECT', 'SELECT COUNT(1) INTO records');
  PREPARE stmt FROM querynew;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; */
  RETURN records;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to write a User defined function like above so as to use it with a select statement and pass a `query string`(a select statement) to it and get the records' count.

For ex -

```
SELECT test('SELECT 1');
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get it running. Have tried many alterations but none successful.

Comment: `SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers.`. See [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: Yeah, I read about that. Hence wrote "maybe".
Although still not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: When I write a static query like - 
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO records FROM `xyz` just before returning the output, it works just fine. But I am not able to figure out how to run the query from a variable.

Comment: Using [14.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) you can run the query from a variable, but not in the context of a stored function. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ugjdFmr9k2v3UXWG4tA87C/2

Comment: But how do I do it for a function? This will work for stored procedures. But the issue with stored procedures is that you cannot call it from inside a select statement.